# How can I override postgres row values with values from a different row in the same table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table representing user settings, and each row is an update to those settings. I want to implement a toggle switch where, if toggled on for a particular setting, we always use the latest value for that setting (while leaving all other settings unchanged). Ex:

| Setting | Enabled | Use latest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Setting version C | true | false |
| Setting version B | false | false |
| Setting version A | false | true |

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to structure a query so that:

- When I fetch setting version B, I get `enabled: false` because use latest is set to false
- When I fetch setting version A, I get enabled: true, because use latest is set to true, and the value from Setting version C is "latest"

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Huh? Why not just set `enabled` to what you want for each version? Assuming that is to simple, how are you arriving at `latest`?

Comment: Because "use latest" will not always be enabled. I need the ability to flip back and forth between the latest state of the setting and the original state. For further context, these settings are powering instances of a workflow. When a workflow is started, it either needs to the use the settings that existed at the time it was created, or if configured as such, it should use the latest version of the workflow settings. And sometimes, people might want to have it use the latest settings, but then later change their mind and revert to the original ones.

Comment: You still have not said how you are defining latest?

Comment: Latest is a toggle switch managed by the end user for each individual setting. So in practice there will be a bunch of settings, and the user might want to use the latest version for one of those settings while leaving the rest alone.

Comment: Is it the case that you want to query that table and if the `enabled` column is `false` then the query should return whatever is in the `use latest` column and if `enabled` is `true` then you want the query to return the literal `"latest"`?

Comment: So `latest` is the version that has `enabled` = `True`? If that is the case would it be less confusing to have it be `Use current`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown other way around, I want to query the table, and if `use latest` is true, it should return whatever is in the `enabled` column for the most recently created record. If the `use latest` column is false, then it should return its own value.

Comment: " I want to query the table, and if use latest is true, it should return whatever is in the enabled column for the most recently created record." - Is there something in the table that indicates what the most recently created record is?

Comment: There's a created_at timestamp, as well as a primary key. Either would work.